# g++ 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Tags: gcc, null, g++

I'm using gcc-4.7.1 on windows 8 Release Preview with git-bash.

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\Users\nikhil bhardwaj\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/users/nikhil bhardwaj/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w
64-mingw32/4.7.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn/source/gcc/configure --host=x8
6_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,
c++,objc,obj-c++ --with-gmp=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn/build/for_target --
enable-twoprocess --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/hom
e/drangon/work/mingw-w64-dgn/target --with-sysroot=/home/drangon/work/mingw-w64-
dgn/target
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.1 20120524 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

When I try to compile a small code snippet,

```
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left, *right;
};
node *newNode(int data)
{
    node *node = new (struct node);
    node->data = data;
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

I get this error,

```
$ g++ -I../includes bst.cpp
bst.cpp: In function 'node* newNode(int)':
bst.cpp:13:18: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this sc
bst.cpp:14:19: error: 'NULL' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm not able to use either `NULL` or `nullptr`, do I need to include some header files?

Comment: NULL is defined in a number of the C-legacy headers (`<cstddef>` is probably the preferred header in C++).  It is not a keyword that is automatically defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try in c++11 mode:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I../includes bst.cpp
```

Comment: Any ideas how I can get vim to not mark that line as an error?

Comment: I don't see that behavior, are you using a plugin?

Comment: try updating the cpp.vim file (http://www.assembla.com/code/ajbhome-config/subversion/nodes/config/trunk/vim/vimfiles/syntax/cpp.vim?rev=58)